# Control memory bandwidth in Gem5

Tags: gem5

Is there any way to control memory bandwidth in Gem5? I want to analyze the impact of memory bandwidth on a micro-benchmark by varying the bandwidth. From stats I could see that, Gem5 gives details on consumed read and write bandwidth at memory controller, but I want to change the available memory bandwidth to throttle it or relax it.

Thanks in advance